# Version control system for KiCAD which can deal with merge requests

Tags: pcb-design, kicad

When working on a project with a group of people it is often required to merge changes someone else has made into a master version of the project. However my EDA of chocie, KiCAD, does not seem to support this. I've seen alot of people doing version control in git. However after trying this the merge conflicts are horrifying. Altium seems to have a nice tool to do [this](https://www.altium.com/solutions/by-technology/team-collaboration) however I would like to stay with KiCAD. I am trying to find a way to do a diff on revisions of a board and schematics, can KiCAD do this?

Comment: [Have you seen this project?](https://jnavila.github.io/plotkicadsch/)

Comment: No, but it looks like what I am looking for. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet.

There is a plan to implement it, but this is a hard problem, because text based diff/merge operates on one-dimensional data, while schematics have two, and board design files have three dimensions. There is no sensible way to normalize the data in order to get minimal diffs.